Proof by induction of $V(r) \subset V(s)$, where the Vs are neighboords of $e$ in a topological group.
Some context:
I'm trying to fill the details of a proof concerning neighborhoods indexed by dyadic rational numbers. Suppose we have a sequence $U_n$ of symmetric neighborhoods of $e \in G$ such that $U_{n+1}^2 \subset U_n$. One can construct neighborhoods $V$ inductively and we have the following:
Let $V(1) = U_0$, and assuming the neighborhoods $V(m/2^n)$ were defined for $m = 1,\cdots, 2^n$, put
$V(1/2^{n+1}) = U_{n+1}$
$V(2m/2^{n+1}) = V(m/2^m), m = 1,\cdots, 2^n$
$V((2m+1)/2^{n+1}) = V(m/2^n)\cdot V(1/2^{n+1}), m = 1, \cdots, 2^n - 1$
And if $m > 2^n$, just put $V(m/2^n) = G$.
In addition, I proved the following property
$V(m/2^n)\cdot V(1/2^n) \subset V((m+1)/2^n)$.
Now I want to prove that if $r,s$ are dyadic positive rationals numbers such that $r<s$, i.e, $r = m/2^n$ and $s = k/2^n$, where $m < k$ (I'm assuming both have the same denominator cause I can just multiply and divide by 2 to reach this), then $V(r) \subset V(s)$.
My approach is to use induction on $n$ and consider the cases: both $m$ and $k$ are even, both $m$ and $k$ are odd, $m$ is odd and $k$ even, $m$ is even and $k$ odd. I was succesful in the cases $m$ and $k$ have the same parity, but I'm struggling in the other case. Can someone help?
By the way, is this a good approach? maybe I'm overcomplicating the problem
